# How to group multiple subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to group a series of subqueries but keep getting the same result for each row.

```
     SELECT Campaign_Name,
                    (SELECT COUNT(Bounce)
                    FROM `temp_Data`) AS Sent, (SELECT COUNT(Bounce)
                                            FROM `temp_Data` 
                                            WHERE Bounce = '0') AS  Delivered, (SELECT SUM(Opened) 
                                                        FROM `temp_Data`
                                                        WHERE Opened = '1')AS Opened
FROM temp_Data

GROUP BY Campaign_Name
```

the results are:

```
Campaign Name  Sent Delivered Opened
Campaign1      300   278       196
Campaign2      300   278       196
```

my data is in 0,1 so even when I do sum it still gives me similar result.

How can I get the individual count for each campaign?

Comment: Change `where clause` You dont change it.

Comment: Show us how is your table schema.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single query

```
SELECT
    Campaign_Name,
    COUNT(*) AS Sent,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Bounce = '0' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Delivered,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Opened = '1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Opened
FROM temp_Data
GROUP BY Campaign_Name
```

Take a look at [control functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) and [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html).

The tricky part is that `COUNT` does not increment for `NULL` values, so I'm using that to do a selective count.

Comment: Thanks, but your code comes back with a syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 1 ELSE NULL) AS Delivered,
    COUNT(CASE Opened = '1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL) AS' at line 4

Comment: I think I fixed it. Please check now.

Comment: I updated the answer.
Sorry, I don't have MySQL installed so I can't test. Also added relevant links, please take a look if it's still not working as I put it. That's the main idea.